# Pairwise correlation and dropping variable with the lowest correlation to the dependent in Python

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, feature-selection, pairwise

I am currently trying to clean my dataset, and would like to remove variables that are correlated between one another. I have seen some code that has been previously shared doing this, but there doesn't seem to be any criteria for what variable is dropped. I am trying to get it so that the variable that has the lower correlation to the dependent is removed.

My dataset is in the format:

Name | Dependent | x1 | x2 | x3 | xn |

I have tried this so far, but it seems not to work. Any suggestions on how to change my code would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('tetrahymena_padel_withDep.csv')
dataf1 = dataset.drop(['Name'], axis = 1)
dataf2 = dataset.drop(['Name', 'Dependent'], axis = 1)

corrWithDep = dataf1.corr().iloc[0]
corrWithVar = dataf2.corr()

col_corr = set()

for i in range(len(corrWithVar.columns)):
    for j in range(i):
        if (corrWithVar.iloc[i, j] >= 0.9) and (corrWithVar.columns[j] not in col_corr):
            if (corrWithDep.iloc[i] >= corrWithDep.iloc[j]):
                colname = corrWithVar.columns[j]
                col_corr.add(colname)
            else:
                colname = corrWithVar.columns[i]
                col_corr.add(colname)
            
                if colname in dataset.columns:
                    del dataset[colname]
```